# using data.table::fread to import data but get NA columns

Tags: r, csv, import, data.table

I have a `.csv` data, including 39635 obs. of 11 variables.
However, I use `data.table::fread()` to import my data and get 13 variables.
All cells under 12 and 13 column are `NA`.
How can I control it to import correctly?

```
dt <- data.table::fread("data.csv", header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

I know I can use `select`: Vector of column names or numbers to keep, drop the rest and `drop`: Vector of column names or numbers to drop, keep the rest.
Is there other ways to solve this?

**UPDATE**
my data:

```
col1 col2 col3 .....  col11
A    123  ABC  .....  123456
B    234  XYZ  .....  987654
```

After importing:

```
col1 col2 col3 .....  col11   V1  V2
A    123  ABC  .....  123456  NA  NA
B    234  XYZ  .....  987654  NA  NA
```

where `NA` is not character. it means missing value.

Comment: Did you meant `strip.white` ?

Comment: @RichScriven I can provide it. But the problem is my `.csv` data in column 12 and 13 contains `NA`.

Comment: @akrun I have already use `strip.white = T`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't you just do `select=1:11`?  That *is* the right way.

Comment: If you want to do it in an automated way, then read `dt` in and then filter with `dt[, whatever, with=FALSE]` where whatever is your criterion, maybe `colSums(dt) != nrow(dt)` or something.

Comment: @RichScriven I know that. However, I want to do it automatically so that I don't need to check if I import similar data in the future. I can create a template R code.

Comment: @Frank I update my question for a small example. `colSums()` must be numeric. but my data contains character

Comment: Oh sorry, `colSums(is.na(dt))`.